# How to proceed correctly in angular when the user reloads the page with f5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular4-router

I am new at Angular 2-4 and right now I am having problems when the page is reloaded with f5. As I have seen, the problem is that I am navigating towards the same route and therefore the ngOnInit() is not loaded again. In the ngOnInit() is where I initialize some of the variables and dynamic forms that I use. I have seen a possible solution that is to subscribe to the parameters of the route and there call a method that initializes everything. Something like this:

```
this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(
params => {
   this.paramX = params['paramX'];
   this.initializeComponent();
});

private initializeComponent() {

}
```

Is that the correct way to do it? Is that a good practice or should I do it in another way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you refresh the page you _do_ run `ngOnInit()` again, and all other lifecycle hooks, since you're reloading the entire application from scratch. That said, the pattern you presented is good.

Comment: but I am using routing and as I understand it when I reload with f5 it enters the same route and does not refresh the component so it does not execute the ngOnInit () either. That is why it is necessary to subscribe to be able to find out about the change. I'm wrong?

Comment: It does refresh the _entire application_ (down to app.component). Think about it. When you reload the browser window, it dumps whatever was in `window` and loads everything from the server (or cache) but you lose the entire application state. Angular is no different from any other app. That said, the best way to handle router parameters _is_ to subscribe to the router because this lets you react to a parameter change _after_ the component is instantiated because you can't rely on the component only being instantiated once with one parameter.

Comment: What you're thinking of is calling `router.navigate[...]` to your present, already-loaded location with identical parameters: that does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To formalize my comment: if you use the browser's refresh/reload, or [`Location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) to refresh any page on an angular application, you do run `ngOnInit()` again, and all other [life-cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

This is because you are reloading the *entire application from scratch*, all the way down to `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` and then re-bootstrapping everything. That's what refresh *does*.

If you need a demonstration, open [Developer Tools and set a breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) in your Component's `ngOnInit()` and hit refresh. You will stop at the breakpoint.

The phrasing in your later comment "enters the same route" presumes that there *is already* a known route. There is not, because the application is entirely re-bootstrapped.

You may be thinking of calling [`router.navigate([...])`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) to your present location with identical path parameters. This will not emit a [`NavigationStart`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart) event and the router will not attempt to load anything (because why would it, you haven't navigated anywhere). That, in turn, will *not* call `ngOnInit()`.

That said, **yes**, the way you are currently handing path parameters is the best solution, chiefly because it allows you to react to changes in the path *without forcing you* to reinitialize the Component.

Put another way, if all of your Component logic relies on the dynamic path parameter being set OnInit, what happens if the parameters changes after the component is instantiated? Nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed description and your help.

Comment: @RidelHernándezInfante My pleasure.